# How does Enzyme deal with asynchronicity in its attempt to stay synchronized with the React component tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to understand Enzyme's component tree synchronization with the React component tree, and somes cases are not clear to me.

Enzyme stays synchronized with the following changes:

```
(async () => setLogo({ logo: "j" }))();
```

But not with the following:

```
  Promise.resolve().then(() => setLogo({ logo: "j" }));
```

The latter requires me to manually [`update`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) the Enzyme component tree, while the former does not.

It would seem logical to me that both require manual sync, as both of them are asynchronous changes. I don't understand why one does require it while the other does not.

Can someone explain to me how Enzyme deals with asynchronicity in its attempt to stay synchronized with the React component tree and how this difference between a promise and an async function call happens?

Comment: That's because in the first case, setLogo runs synchronously/immediately. In the second, it runs on a successive tick. If you added an `await null;` in there before the setLogo, the first and second cases would be identical.

This isn't how enzyme works, it's how JavaScript works.